# How many players must own Mario Bros for 2 player mode?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, mario-bros

There's a version of the original Mario Bros (https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/steaDexI7H4v0UEWC20wW3alYYaGW5bz) available for the 3DS on the Nintendo eShop.  If I buy this eShop version, can I play with my friends even if they haven't also bought it?

Answer (score 1):

The page states "2 Player Alternating", which usually means that you will have to do something like pass the actual 3DS from one player to another, rather than, say, playing together through an online connection or other means. So technically, yes, it appears you can play with friends, but it means that they likely need to be in the same physical space as you so you can share the console.

Comment: Hmmm, the detailed info in the eShop, when viewed on the 3DS, says it features "2P Download Play" - but I'm not sure if that's 1 or two copies. And I really can't fathom how a "pass and play" style experience would work with Mario Bros.

Comment: Hm, usually it says how many copies - I would think 2P download play might mean you can play with one copy.

Comment: Download Play is just that: One copy shared. So if the eshop says 2P download play, you just have to be within infered range to be able to do such: Download play works like that. (I've used that feature for years.)